# Firestore creating a sequence of numbers +1 to the number before even when several users reads at the same time

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im building an app that creates orders and connects a customer with a "seller".

Every order must have a number that goes in sequence to the order created before.

For this I have a firebase firestore document that stores all order numbers like this:

0001,
0002,
0003,
...
...
0098,
0099
and so on.

My problem is that if two orders are created at the same time, then both read from the same list and sets its number in this case to 0100, which leads to two orders with the same number.
It should instead be one order with 0100 and one with 0101.

Is this possible to implement in any way?

And to make it clear I dont want to use a random number to separate orders, they must be in sequence because of other features in the app.

Im using flutter.

Comment: use transaction. firebase transactions are atomic and provide this feature.

Comment: Use transaction, as Rahul wrote, or just generate random IDs for every document and count them using `FieldValue.increment(1)` or `increment(1)` in seller's document and app document (overall sold items by sellers).

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other members that will encounter this issue:

As stated by @Rahul and @Mises;
You should use Firebase transaction which is an atomic operation for reading and writing data. In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.

You may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#dart) for more information.